# Google App Engine Datastore index cap

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Can somebody explain the 5000 index cap in the Datastore in plain English.
Does that mean that an indexed list property of a stored object cannot have more the 5000 elements?

Answer (score 10):

The Datastore limits the number of index entries that a single entity can have, this limit is set to 5000 elements per entity.

You can test this limit easily using the [Interactive shell](http://shell.appspot.com/) with the following snippet:

```
class Model(db.Model):
   x = db.ListProperty(int)

entity = Model(x = range(5001))
entity.put()

'Too many indexed properties for entity %r.' % self.key())
BadRequestError: Too many indexed properties for entity  
datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Model', 0, _app=u'shell')
```

Comment: *How* does your example illustrate this limit? This answer is still not very plain to me.

Comment: What your example illustrates.  There is no explanation of what the code does and how this reaches the limit.

Comment: ah ok, it is pretty trivial; basically the code is trying to insert a entity to the datastore with a list of 5001 elements but gae does not allow it raising a `Too many indexed` exception. Trying with 5000 elements should work instead.

Comment: When you say "elements" do you mean a single property on a single entity with a list of 5001 values, or 5001 "rows" (what I would call entities) each with a different value for the property "x"? (I'm using Java so I'm trying to translate, and I'm not sure if datastore support is identical).  What I'm trying to figure out if you have 5001 different entities (same kind) with 5001 different values for the same indexed property if you get the same error.

Comment: @NickC a single property on a single entity with a list of 5001 values, that's it.

Comment: I was confused with this example myself, but it seems like to me, that `entity` has a list with 5001 values. and since it's a `ListProperty` datastore pops an error because it tries to make 5001 separate indexes for each value (Datastore creates an index for every property and ListProperty value)...

I think the limit is 5000 indexes per entity, so if you have 5001 separate entities with different values, I think it should be fine. But I am not 100% because I am new to datastore myself. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, *Yes* if you indexed the property.

App Engine limits the number of property values a single entity can have on an index (number of rows * the number of columns) since it needs to create an index for each permutation.  In the case of a single index property you have 5000rows * 1column = 5000.

To show why App Engine does this let's take the example from their [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes).

Model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
   x = db.StringListProperty()
   y = db.StringListProperty()
```

Index.yaml

```
indexes:
- kind: MyModel
  properties:
  - name: x
  - name: y
```

Execution

```
e2 = MyModel()
e2.x = ['red', 'blue']
e2.y = [1, 2]
e2.put()
```

In this case, App Engine will have to create 12 indexes for this datastore entry alone, since effectively you can search for any combination of values:

```
x1
x2
y1
y2
x1 y1
x1 y2
x2 y1
x2 y2
y1 x1
y1 x2
y2 x1
y2 x2
```

Now if you had 100 values in each property, you can imagine that the list would sky rocket to an obscene amount of queries.

The equation is *something* like this:

```
len(x) + len(y) + (len(x)-1 * len(y) * (len(x) + len(y))) = number of indexed

**2 values per property**
2 + 2 + (1 * 2 * (2 + 2)) = 12

**100 values per property**
100 + 100 + (99 * 100 * (100 + 100)) = 1,980,200
```

Comment: So here's my live example. I have a Calendar class and a child class, Event. Calendar has a list property of type List<Event>. My question is, can this list have more than 5000 indexed elements (events). I actually added over 5000 instances of event to that list and everything got stored with no errors, therefore I am confused. I may not understand the inner workings of the datastore, so any clarification is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, to clarify. Im am not using a custom index for that list, but GAE is automatically generating one because of the nature of the property.

Comment: You can have a list of more then 5000 items if you property is not 'indexed'.  If your property is indexed, the maximum amount is 5000.  To set a property not to be indexed you need to do following CalendarEvents = ListProperty(Event, indexed=False)

Comment: @oviroa This sounds like a very odd way to model a calendar. It would make more sense for the Event entities to have a ReferenceProperty referring to the calendar they're in.

Comment: This "answer" adds confusion by also using composite indexes, besides being wrong. First, there's only 8 index rows, not 12 (4 property indexes and 2*2 composite indexes). Second, composite indexes are created in the defined order, so you won't have any "y1 x*" or "y2 x*" rows. However, you could do equality query for x and y, but only equality on x and ASC sorting by y, unless you also define a second composite index with the property names swapped.