# Cap on indexed properties

Tags: google-app-engine

The latest information I can find seems to say 5000 indexes for both manual and automatic. But this information is old and probably outdated.

[New cap on indexed properties per entity](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/1fTct9AO1MY)

> As a heads up, we've recently added a cap on the total number
>   of indexed property values that a single entity may have. This
>   includes both normal property values (excluding Text and Blob) and
>   index rows generated by your app's indexes. The cap is currently 5000.

Over here the most recent info [Google App Engine Datastore index cap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131247/google-app-engine-datastore-index-cap) is also probably outdated since the most upvoted answer gives an example failure that now works.

Or does this limit only apply to configured indexes and not to property indexes?
I know that this limit applies to entity and not kind. Mostly I would like to know if there is a hard limit on how many elements a ListProperty can have (with only the regular property indexes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the AppEngine Datastore documentation, [Quotas and Limits](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Quotas_and_Limits) section, the current cap is 20,000